# Error running Deploy only YYY: Address localhost:8081 is already in use

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-14, tomcat8.5

Intellij and windows1o system throwing the 'Error running Deploy only YYYY: Address localhost:8081 is already in use'. Need your suggestions to resolve this error in Deploying only YYYY.

Comment: kill java process and restart your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same issue some days back,reason is other web server is already running on that port,what you need to do is

1.open cmd and type `netstat -ano` and check for the process running on port 8081 and note the PID

2.Now go to Task Manager,under services tab check for a running web service having same PID,delete that process.

3.Now restart the Tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you  very much for responding to my question. When I ran the netstat -o  command, I did not find any process running with port 8081.  Wondering in this scenario , what should be the solution.

Comment: try this once  netstat -a -n -o | find "8081" ,if you don't get anything means there is no process running on port 8081

Comment: if the solution worked for you,please up vote and accept it as answer,thank you.